# How do I create sections in a f.select input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Posts model which `belongs_to: Category`.

When I create the post I can select from a list of categories which it belongs to. 
My model category has a name and a gender attribute.
So, for example, some categories are "Accessories", "Jeans", "Shirts" (with gender "Male"), and the same for gender "female".

I could precede all of the names of the categories with men or women, i.e.: "Men's Jeans", "Women's Jeans", but I would prefer to separate the `f.select` into two sections - "Men", "Women". Something that would look like this:

```
Men
  Accessories
  Jeans
  etc
Women
  Accessories
  Jeans
  etc
```

The category does have the gender attribute, so I can differentiate by that as well as by ID because the first 10 id's belong to men and the next 10 belong to women. I just don't know how to show this within an `f.select`. Here is my current `select`:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, @categories.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ]} %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as always!

**EDIT**

Alright my helper method is

```
def option_groups_from_collection_for_select(collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method)
  collection.map do |group|
    option_tags = options_from_collection_for_select(
      group.send(group_method), option_key_method, option_value_method)

    content_tag(:optgroup, option_tags, :label => group.send(group_label_method))
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

and select is

```
<%= f.select(:type_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :types, :category, :id, :name)) %>
```

This is getting the correct category & type and looks good, but when I go and edit the post, the select doesn't show the currently selected item.

Comment: Don't put that logic in a view. It should be inside a controller. Build an array or a hash containing what you want to display in the controller, then iterate over it in the view.

Answer (score 1):

See [grouped_collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select). It'll look like this:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:category_id, Category.top_level, :children, :name, :id, :name %>
```